# Compile a dictionary in the least computational costly way

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have two lists `tokens_e_set` and `tokens_f_set` and I want to map every possible combination of every element of the two as key in a dictionary `t_e_f`. Every of these keys has also to have a value that is `1/len(tokens_e_set)`. I was looking for a way to do it in the fastest way, since I have to work with very long lists of tokens. The code is as following:

```
init_value=1/len(tokens_e_set)
t_e_f=collection.defaultdict(float)
for word_e in tokens_e_set:
    for word_f in tokens_f_set:
        t_e_f[(word_e,word_f)]=init_value
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can get execution times using `timeit` or `cProfile`. Then you can try the various proposals and find the fastest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `product` instead of nested for loops.

Since you are initializing a dict with many keys, all with the same value, then `dict.fromkeys` seems the best way to go.

```
from itertools import product
t_e_f = dict.fromkeys(product(tokens_e_set,tokens_f_set),1.0/len(tokens_e_set))
```

(Comparison timings left as an exercise for the OP.)

Comment: Without timeit every answer is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison timings:

```
C:\Python27>python lib\timeit.py -s "tokens_e_set=tokens_f_set=range(100)" -s "import collections" "t_e_f=collections.defaultdict(float);init_value=1/len(tokens_e_set)" "for word_e in tokens_e_set:" " for word_f in tokens_f_set:" "  t_e_f[word_e,word_f]=init_value"
100 loops, best of 3: 2.61 msec per loop

C:\Python27>python lib\timeit.py -s "tokens_e_set=tokens_f_set=range(100)" -s "from itertools import product" "t_e_f = dict.fromkeys(product(tokens_e_set,tokens_f_set),1.0/len(tokens_e_set))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 msec per loop
```

How these scale left as an exercise for the questionner.